# How to effectively visualize multiple frequency polygons in ggplot2?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I apologize if this is not the appropriate site for this question. I am asking here because my question is about data visualization.

I am comparing 5 distributions in R. So, I tried using frequency polygons with different colors. Following is the code and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
ggplot() +
  geom_freqpoly(data = dg101,
                mapping = aes(x = abs(slo_v_m), y = ..count../sum(..count..),
                              color = "Ob"), size = 1) +
  geom_freqpoly(data = acc17 ,
                aes(x = abs(saccm), y = ..count../sum(..count..),
                    color = "B"),  size = 1) +
  geom_freqpoly(data = acc19 ,
                aes(x = abs(saccm), y = ..count../sum(..count..),
                    color = "C"),  size = 1) +
  geom_freqpoly(data = acc16 ,
                aes(x = abs(saccm), y = ..count../sum(..count..),
                    color = "F"),  size = 1) +
  geom_freqpoly(data = acc15 ,
                aes(x = abs(saccm), y = ..count../sum(..count..),
                    color = "Ca"), size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~Vehicle.type, scales = "free") +
  scale_color_manual("", values = c("darkgreen",  "skyblue", "purple", "orange","black")) +
  labs(x = "Acceleration during speed oscillation (m/s^2)",
       y = "Proportion") +
  theme_bw() +
  #theme_stata() + #scale_colour_stata() + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold",
                                  margin=margin(20,20,0,0)),
        legend.position = c(0.85, 0.6),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"))
```

[image]

I want to highlight the `Ob` and `Ca` polygons more. But I am not sure how to do so. What color scheme is better? How can this be made more easy to understand, especially for the `HV` facet?

Comment: You might try just making the other colors a bit transparent. For example, Try `values = c("#00640033", "#87CEEB44", "#A020F0FF", "#FFA50033", "#000000FF")`

Comment: Another way might be to make the lines thicker for Ob & Ca